# Do I need to initialize base class in virtual inheritance classes' constructors for diamond inheritanceproblem?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the diamond problem resolved with virtual inheritance. The situation here is not a diamond but I want to understand the virtual inheritance:

```
class Base
{
public:
    explicit Base(int arg)
        : arg { arg }
    {}
    const int arg;
};

class Virtual : public virtual Base
{
public:
    explicit Virtual(int _arg)
        //: Base(_arg)
    {}
};

class Target : public virtual Virtual
{
public:
    explicit Target(int _arg)
        : Base(_arg),
          Virtual(_arg)
    {}
};
```

So, the idea is that Virtual or Virtual2, inherited together by Target, will have single Base instance. Here I thought that calling Base constructor in Target constructor will create the instance needed and I could omit Base constructor in Virtual, but then I'm getting an error:

> error: constructor for 'Virtual' must explicitly initialize the base class 'Base' which does not have a default constructor

So, is the constructor there really necessary if it's suppose not to be called?

In real situation I am making some changes to arguments with lambda within the constructors so I don't know if it needs to be repeated.

Comment: please show real code, [this has typos and cannot reproduce the error you claim](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p2aGmV9aonSShtLn)

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: fwiw I tried to fix the typos but I got tired before catching them all

Comment: yes, `Target` need to also initialize `Base`

Comment: in the code you posted the virtual inheritance is almost not relevant, none of the classes inherits the same base twice. If `Base` has no default constructor then yes you have to call a different one.

Comment: fixed. I know target needs to initialize Base but I don't know why Virtual needs to. The code I've posted is just an example, I could add Virtual2 class and ask the same... but this is "minimal example" to reproduce my question, now without typos.

Comment: "_but I don't know why Virtual needs to_" - Neither `Base` nor `Virtual` are default constructible so you need to specify the constructor and supply the arguments it needs. Note however that when instantiating `Target` the `Base` will only be initialized directly from `Target` and the argument you pass to `Virtual` is only going to be used by `Virtual`:s constructor, not `Base`: https://godbolt.org/z/vEtuht

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have written, both `Virtual` and `Target` needs
to provide a constructor for `Base`.

If you make `Virtual` abstract, then it does not need
to initialize `Base` any longer.

```
class Base
{
public:
    explicit Base(int arg)
        :  arg(arg)
    {}
private:
    const int arg;
};

class Virtual : public virtual Base
{
public:
    explicit Virtual(int arg)
    {}
private:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Target : public virtual Virtual
{
public:
    explicit Target(int arg)
        : Base(arg), Virtual(arg)
    {}
private:
    virtual void foo() override {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary because otherwise the compiler doesn't know how to call the costructor of `Virtual` on its own, when the object is not a part of furher inheritance chain.  You don't have to provide a constructor for `Virtual`, but when you do, you need to initialise `Base` as well. (If you don't provide a constructor for `Virtual`, you cannot make (sub)objects of this class, which makes it useless for most purposes).

If `Virtual` is an abstract class then its constructor can never be called on its own (only from further derived classes) and the compiler will let you skip initialisation of `Base`.